# Got Sauce in my charging port (Dell)

Tags: dell-inspiron

I have a Dell inspiron. So i got spaghetti sauce in my charger port. when i realized this happened i picked out what i could with a toothpick. i continued to use my laptop. i also later sprayed compressed air, but by then it was probably dried up. i realize where i went wrong, but i’m getting the AC power adapter wattage & type cannot be determined error. So, it turns on but doesn’t charge. the charger i’m using is 65W, it says it’s from dell. What could be the possible issue; battery is broken, the charger, something to do with the charging port or circuit board??

Comment: Compressed air was *not* a good idea, as it forced the sauce into the laptop. Best look up the service manual, disassemble, and *gently clean any spatters with 91% or stronger alcohol and a swab. A possibility is that the charger port connection to the PC board is corroded (electrolytically) and needs to be fixed.

Comment: i sprayed it a day later, so hopefully that effect wasn’t as bad. if it’s corrided is that something you can spot yourself, or someone professional could easily figure out.

Comment: If you have a multimeter and know how to solder, you can try. First try cleaning, though, particularly the socket contacts.

Answer (score 0):

Dell laptop power supplies often have a power connector with a small pin in the center used to signal its capabilities to the laptop. This center pin will tell the laptop what kind of power supply it is and whether it is capable of supplying enough power to charge the battery. If the laptop does not get the expected data from the power supply via this pin, it will power the laptop but will not charge.

My guess is that the connection from the power supply connector center pin to the charger socket inside your laptop has been interrupted either on the side of the connector or on the side of the laptop, perhaps caused by your attempts to clean the socket.

[Here is a discussion about the Dell power connector on the Electrical Engineering StackExchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/327909/3-wires-on-a-bipolar-dc-plug-what-are-they-for)